# how spring-views.properties determines resource

Tags: spring-mvc

spring-views.properties

```
index.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
index.url=path-to-jsp-file
```

controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController { 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message","Maven Web Project + Spring 3 MVC - welcome()");
    return "index";

    }
}
```

How does it tell that the path is "localhost:8080/welcome", yet I have specified index in the spring-views.properties i.e "localhost:8080/index"?

Comment: You are confusing the path to the template/view file with the path to the request mapping.  The former is the short name by which Spring MVC will identify and load some template/view within the file path, the latter is how it maps a given URL request to a Controller method for handling.

Comment: I thought the RequestMapping param must be similar to that used in the view. i.e RequestMapping("/param") in the controller and param.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
param.url=path-to-jsp-file. If not how do I determine the one to use?

Comment: No, they are two separate things.  You determine which view to use based on which view you want the end user to see.  Think of it this way: The `@RequestMapping` maps the URL the user sent to which method in the controller should handle that type of request.  Your controller will then do some processing, then programmatically return the name of the template, or "view", that is needed.  The template is what gets displayed, and you can return any template you want.